# NewGuid vs System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");

Tags: c#, .net, guid

Is there a difference when you generate a GUID using `NewGuid();` vs `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");` or they are the same thing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` is string representation of GUID, i.e. returns `string` object, while `Guid.NewGuid()` returns `Guid` datatype.

Comment: Apart from one is string the other is guid, is the format and generation of the Id the same?

Comment: @001, `Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();` will generate `Guid` object. Calling `string s = guid.ToString();` will create string representation of generated GUID.

Answer (score 174):

I realize that this question already has an accepted answer, but I thought it would be useful to share some information about formatting guids.

The [ToString() (no parameters) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/560tzess.aspx) formats a guid using this format:

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The [ToString(string format) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx) formats a guid in one of several ways:

```
"N" - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (32 digits)
"D" - xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (32 digits separated by hyphens)
"B" - {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} (same as "D" with addition of braces)
"P" - (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx) (same as "D" with addition of parentheses)
"X" - {0x00000000,0x0000,0x0000,{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}}
```

Calling `Guid.ToString("D")` yields the same result as calling `Guid.ToString()`.

As mentioned in the other answers, the guid itself has no format.  It is just a value.  Note, that you can create guids using NewGuid or using the guid's constructor.  Using NewGuid, you have no control over the value of the guid.  Using the guid's constructor, you can control the value.  Using the constructor is useful if you already have a string representation of a guid (maybe you read it from a database) or if you want to make it easier to interpret a guid during development.  You can also use the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx), [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parseexact.aspx), [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx), and [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparseexact.aspx) methods.

So, you can create guids like this:

```
Guid g1 = Guid.NewGuid(); //Get a Guid without any control over the contents
Guid g2 = new Guid(new string('A',32)); //Get a Guid where all digits == 'A'
Guid g3 = Guid.Parse(g1.ToString());
Guid g4 = Guid.ParseExact(g1.ToString("D"),"D");
Guid g5;
bool b1 = Guid.TryParse(g1.ToString(), out g5);
Guid g6;
bool b2 = Guid.TryParseExact(g1.ToString("D"),"D", out g6);
```

Comment: Nice thanks for putting the effort in formatting your answer :)

Comment: This is the most succinct explanation of Guid formatting I've seen.  Good job and thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Using `System.Guid.NewGuid()` you will get a object of `Guid` type

Using `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");` you will get the string representation of `Guid` object

Also as I know no difference between `.ToString("D")` and `.ToString()`

Answer (score 4):

The generation algorithm has to be the same for both, because `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")` is calling `System.Guid.NewGuid()`, and then calling `ToString` on the result, i.e., both of your examples are calling the same method to generate the guid. As to comparing the "format" - this does not make sense because `System.Guid.NewGuid()` does not have a "format" in the same way as `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")` - it is only by calling the `ToString` method that you give the internal representation of the guid an external, string format. The format the string takes will depend on the argument you pass to the string method.