# Retrieving HttpContext in a Custom NLog Target

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, httpcontext

I may me missing something basic here - but is it possible to retrieve the `HttpContext.Current` in a custom NLog event?

I am trying to give each request a unique Guid so that I can correlate logging messages to a single event (i.e, tie together each log event for a single request).  So, I want to store this Guid in `HttpContext.Current.Items`, then retrieve it in the NLog target and include it in the log message.

Here is my example target where I'd like to access `HttpContext.Current`:

```
[Target("AzureTableTarget")]
public class AzureTableTarget : TargetWithLayout
{

    public AzureTableTarget()
    {
        _appSettings = IoCResolver.Get<IAppSettings>();
    }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var correlationId = HttpContext.Current; //This is always null

        var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
        CxLogEventBuilder.Build(_appSettings, logEvent).ForEach(batchOperation.Insert);
        _loggingTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it's easier to retrieve the HTTP Context in a NLog target (works for ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core)

1. Install [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.web) (ASP.NET) or [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.web.aspnetcore) (ASP.NET Core) package
2. For ASP.NET core, follow the [ASP.NET Core - NLog setup](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3)
3. Inherit from `AspNetLayoutRendererBase` (namespace `NLog.Web.LayoutRenderers`)
4. Get the request by calling `var context = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;`

Example:

```cs
[LayoutRenderer("aspnet-sessionid")]
[ThreadSafe]
public class AspNetSessionIdLayoutRenderer : AspNetLayoutRendererBase
{
    protected override void DoAppend(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var context = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var contextSession = context?.Session();
        if (contextSession == null)
        {
             InternalLogger.Debug("HttpContext Session Lookup returned null");
             return;
        }

        builder.Append(contextSession.SessionID); // ASP.NET Core: contextSession.Id
    }
}
```

PS: there are currently many predefined renderers for ASP.NET (Core): https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=aspnet

Answer (score 1):

If your custom target should capture one (or more) context-specific values, then I recommend that your target inherits from TargetWithContext (or AsyncTaskTarget).

It gives the ability to setup and capture `contextproperty`-items. Where the Layout can be assigned to capture context-details. Examples of possible context-details easily available from HttpContext:

https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore

For more details about writing custom-targets:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target-for-structured-logging

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-async-target

Btw. there already exists this custom target that nicely inherits from `AsyncTaskTarget`:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureCosmosTable/

Answer (score 0):

This article about [Working with HttpContext.Current](http://odetocode.com/articles/112.aspx) might help.  The key, for you, might be that when control passes from one thread to another HttpContext.Current in the new thread can be null.

Here is another [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976767/httpcontext-current-is-null-in-my-web-service) from here on SO that describes HttpContext.Current being null in the context of a web service.  The accepted answer suggests turning on ASP.Net compatibility in your web.config file.

I don't know of either of these will help, but they might.  I found them by googling for "HttpContext.Current is null", which yielded quite a number of hits.  I have done very little ASP.NET development, so I can't really comment on HttpContext.Current from my own personal experience.

Given your use case, I would suggest that you look into [System.Diagnostics.CorrelationManager.ActivityId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.correlationmanager.activityid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

One nice feature of ActivityId is that it is "flowed" from parent threads to child threads (including thread pool threads).  I think that it works well with Tasks and Parallel operations.  Works well meaning that the ActivityId, as set in a parent thread, has the expected value in a child thread.

There is not a LayoutRenderer for ActivityId, but it easy enough to write one.  See an example (written against NLog 1.0) here:

[Most useful NLog configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091606/most-useful-nlog-configurations/4098047#4098047)

I'm pretty sure that the "EstimatedBufferSize" stuff is no longer needed, so something like will probably work:

```
[LayoutRenderer("ActivityId")]
class ActivityIdLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
  protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
  {
    builder.Append(Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId);
  }
}
```

If you go this route, you might consider adding a Format property to the ActivityIdLayoutRenderer to allow you to specify the guid format.  See this answer (from me).  It contains a lot of useful information about working with guids.

[NewGuid vs System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513391/newguid-vs-system-guid-newguid-tostringd/7598628#7598628)

See this source file (in NLog's git repository) for an example of how you can implement and use such a Format property:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/LayoutRenderers/GuidLayoutRenderer.cs